# Why does my app crash when changing height or width of my UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm overriding `touchesMoved`, and need to resize my `UIScrollView` when dragging. It will appear as if the top is growing, and the bottom stays put. If I create a new rect, change only the Y coordinate, and set the rect as the new scrollview frame, the scrollview moves around the screen just fine. But if I also change the height of the scrollview, memory usage goes through the roof and does not go back down. I never see the scrollview resizing, and eventually the app crashes. It seems like some other event is being triggered that sets the scrollview back to its original frame. I also have this problem if I try setting the height to a static value, rather than the new calculated height. So the problem isn't in my height calculation. I still have this problem if the scrollview has no child views in it.

Edit: Here is the console output from the organizer, but I don't really understand it.  Even though it says it created a crash log, there is none.

```
Jun  1 05:50:47 Andrews-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: void IMGSGXParameterBuffer::checkUsageForGrow() - WARNING - PB unable to grow, as max size reached (0)->(0)
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad rocket.launcher[879] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad UserEventAgent[13] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.timed[836]) <Notice>: (com.apple.timed) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.timed[836]) <Notice>: (com.apple.timed) Exited: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x8c25][845]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x8c25]) Exited: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.accountsd[842]) <Notice>: (com.apple.accountsd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.accountsd[842]) <Notice>: (com.apple.accountsd) Exited: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.geod[867]) <Notice>: (com.apple.geod) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.geod[867]) <Notice>: (com.apple.geod) Exited: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.networkd_privileged[843]) <Notice>: (com.apple.networkd_privileged) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.networkd_privileged[843]) <Notice>: (com.apple.networkd_privileged) Exited: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.afcd[853]) <Notice>: (com.apple.afcd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.afcd[853]) <Notice>: (com.apple.afcd) Exited: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[858]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[858]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Exited: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.mobile.installd[852]) <Notice>: (com.apple.mobile.installd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.mobile.installd[852]) <Notice>: (com.apple.mobile.installd) Exited: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:53 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0x8c25]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:54 Andrews-iPad SpringBoard[67] <Warning>: Memory level is not normal. Pending auto-relaunch of 'com.facebook.Facebook' until it is.
Jun  1 05:50:54 Andrews-iPad SpringBoard[67] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Jun  1 05:50:54 Andrews-iPad rocket.launcher[879] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: failed to map 20672 bytes (4)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: missing mask layer 0x0
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Error>: CoreAnimation: serialization error from context -1571794281
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0x8cb9][838]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0x8cb9]) Exited: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.tccd[841]) <Notice>: (com.apple.tccd) Exited: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x71eb][840]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x71eb]) Exited: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0x8cb9]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad SpringBoard[67] <Warning>: Memory level is not normal. Pending auto-relaunch of 'com.apple.mobilephone' until it is.
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.svs.rocket-launcher[0xd0ce][879]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.svs.rocket-launcher[0xd0ce]) Exited: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:55 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad com.apple.debugserver-199[878] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [036e/1303]: error: ::read ( 5, 0x2fe809fc, 18446744069414585344 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x71eb]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad SpringBoard[67] <Warning>: Memory level is not normal. Pending auto-relaunch of 'com.apple.mobilemail' until it is.
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.svs.rocket-launcher[0xd0ce]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad ReportCrash[882] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad ReportCrash[882] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2013-06-01-055056.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad UserEventAgent[13] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:56 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:57 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:58 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:58 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:50:58 Andrews-iPad backboardd[26] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 3001: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Jun  1 05:51:00 Andrews-iPad profiled[862] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Idled.
Jun  1 05:51:00 Andrews-iPad profiled[862] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service stopping.
Jun  1 05:51:06 Andrews-iPad ReportCrash[885] <Notice>: Not saving Jetsam log because no data from the kernel.
Jun  1 05:51:09 Andrews-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[886] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Jun  1 05:51:09 Andrews-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[886] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/DB71F931-885C-4919-B8D1-F52B3AD784B0 (sandbox)
Jun  1 05:51:39 Andrews-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[890] Builtin profile: MobileMail (sandbox)
```

Comment: Have you tried using a pan gesture recognizer?

Comment: i have all gestures overridden.  my app is a somewhat complex music interface, and nothing is really standard on it.  i don't think this should matter since anything else i do with user interaction works just fine, including only changing the y coordinate of the scrollview.

Comment: what about crash logs?

Comment: I pasted in the console output from the organizer.  Unfortunately it didn't paste well onto here.  For some reason there is no crash log, even though it says one has been created.

Comment: What do you mean by: "have all gestures overridden"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I'm not using any gestures and I'm manually handling user interaction.